# google chrome plugin extension from django app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I a trying a google chrome plugin for my app in django.I loaded my page in a iframe can i use the backend data from the page and create new form for the the google plugin without writing an api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new view for the plugin with required size then load it in i frame